# Meteor methods on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, security, meteor

When I write meteor methods for collections I usually put them in a shared directory so they can be simulated on the client for fast speeds. However is this secure? Should I put methods in the server directory and if so which kind of methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the way meteor is supposed to work for the general case. You are supposed to implement most of your collection methods (update, insert, remove) client side only, and check the updates rights server side.

If you have a collection with some posts, do not make a `Meteor.call('addNewPost', newPost)`. And the a `Posts.insert(...)` in the `addNewPost` meteor method server side. This would be the classic way with a REST API ; but this is meteor :)

You go client side directly for a `Posts.insert(...)`. This will be displayed client side right away and will try to update the base server side.

Then server side, you have to set extensive permissions :

```
Posts.allow({

    'insert': function(userId, doc) {
        // Check if the user exists
        // if he has the right to insert
        // if what he tries to insert is ok for you
        // ...
    },

    'update': function(userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
        // same, width the fields, the doc, the user...
    },

    'remove': function(userId, docs) {
        // same again
    }

});
```

You can `allow()` or `deny()`on anything you can do on a collection. This may seem weird but this is the real basis of good latency compensation. It may be a HUDGE security breach if you do not know how to set up your permission as they need to be. But if you know how to do that, there are absolutely not security issue.

(my advice is to deny everything but the specific elements you want to allow)

So :

1. the user updates his database client side with a client side method : myCollection.update()
2. he sees the results
3. meteor does its magic to send it to the server
4. the server check if this is allowed
5. if yes, write in base and send to the other subscribers
6. if not, send a request to revert the change client side

Comment: Thanks, I have create permissions for all my collections now to enforce security, so it doesn't matter if my methods are clientside and I have allow/deny? Or should they be moved to the server directory for max security

Comment: I don't know if the allow / deny system will be triggered client side.  My first guess is no. I'd say it's a pure server part. I think that adding these elements to your client code will only add fat to your final client js.

Comment: I have put the allow/deny code in my collections folder so is shared in both client and server, so hopefully it should run in both

Answer (score 0):

yes. you can make it safe and have shared directory for collections. Meteor latency compensation feature works only if you have collections in both server and client.
if you are using a shared code for collections you must do these.

- remove insecure, autopublish packages
- use [publish/subscribe](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish)
- configure [allow/deny](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) rules for each collection

more on meteor security.
http://security-resources.meteor.com/

Comment: Thanks, so I can have shared methods and they will still be as secure as server only methods?

Comment: keep in mind that shared code is sent to client also so anyone can view it. It depends on what you want to archive. If you are asking about Meteor.methods limit it only to server.

Comment: I am talking about Meteor.methods, but I thought it's faster if shared as meteor can simulate the method

Comment: ok i was wrong you can have Meteor.methods on client side. the answer for is it secure? It depends on what you want to archive. Always keep in mind that shared code is sent to client also so anyone can view it.

Comment: I don't have any secret keys / tokens in my methods so what kind of thing could people do if they saw the methods?

Comment: they can override it on client side

Comment: so if they can override any method on client side surely all methods should go in server only for security reasons?